# unzip into subdirectory in Linux

Tags: linux, compression

I have a zip file, and would like to unzip a subdirectory of it to another subdirectory, overwriting all existing files. How can this be done in Linux?

Example:
The zip file hi.zip has a "me" folder in it.  I would like to extract only the files/folders inside "me" to a folder on the system named "/home/zzz/".  However, "/home/zzz/" already has files in it with the same names. I'd like to replace those with the new ones in the hi.zip file.

Comment: In the future consider using http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

```
unzip -o hi.zip me/\* -d /home/zzz
```

should do the trick. I suggest you test it first to make sure you don't overwrite the wrong files.

Comment: This does not work for me; the top directory in the zip file is copied to the destination directory.